# Compression using C# and Uncompression using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, compression, gzipstream

I have json string something like this

```
[ { "SectionDataId": "85247","Product":  "0.00"},{ "SectionDataId": "85249","Product":  "12.38"},{ "SectionDataId": "85264","Product":  "0.00"}]
```

Which I have compressed using C# code found on this forum

```
 private string encode(string json)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        ms.Position = 0;
        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] compressed = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);
        byte[] gzBuffer = new byte[ms.Length + 4];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 4, compressed.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(gzBuffer);
    }
```

This output string I have given as web service output so i can use this string in javascript. but I was not able to uncompress the string using javascript.I there any javascript library or code to solve this problem.

Comment: You should use HTTP compression, so the compression and decompression is done for you by the HTTP, instead of rolling your own scheme.

Comment: @dtb could you direct me to useful url where they have implemented in webservice and used in javascript

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression Looks like you just have to set the `Accept-Encoding` header.

Comment: @weston is there any uncompression function in javascript for the above code.

Comment: No idea, but you don't need it. I'm with dtb, don't roll your own, use what's there already.

Comment: @weston  Actually json string length is more  than  100,000.is and it gives error at javascript .so is there any solution to avoid this...

Comment: @weston is there any alternate solution to do this...???

Comment: You are much better off starting with the error as the basis of the question. "how can I get around this error" and post the javascript error.

Comment: how to download a file from url by these compression?